# What does "[Web|App].config('\template')" do?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, t4

I recently got a bullshit detector test for a .NET back-end job.

There was only one question that really puzzled me a bit:

> What does "[Web|App].config('\template')" do?

Honestly to me it looked like a t4 template or a .net project build config or maybe a JavaScript framework configuration. It was a bit (completely) out of context, with no one to ask more details about it...

I just wrote, "Without context it's a bit hard to tell", I just assumed it was some random JS code, and said the code might not work regardless of the values of Web or App cause there is no built-in config method defined with the `Array` prototype...

I am really curious about what can be the context of this one-liner...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got my answer, it was just a dummy Regex... (yet another solution).